# GLFW Mouse doesnt work on Ubuntu+Unity

Tags: mouse, glfw, ubuntu-unity

I have small problem with mouse in glfw ;/. Its working on Windows and Ubuntu+Gnome3, but it doesnt work on Ubuntu+Unity.
Code for my mouse ( im using it to rotating camera in my game ) :

```
    glfwDisable(GLFW_MOUSE_CURSOR);
    int xpos, ypos;
    int w,h;

    glfwGetMousePos(&xpos, &ypos); // im calculating rot of camera with these values
    glfwGetWindowSize(&w,&h); // set mouse
    glfwSetMousePos(w/2, h/2); //  to center of window.
```

And it just doesnt work, but when i set glfwEnable(GLFW_MOUSE_CURSOR); it's working but then mouse is visible ;/ what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
i dont know why, but when i enabled VSYNC in graphics card settings, mouse is working well o.o?
[/SOLVED]